# How to fix Swift warning in iOS "Multiple Closures with Trailing Closure Violation"

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am fairly new to Swift development and I'm getting the following warning:

> Multiple Closures with Trailing Closure Violation: Trailing closure
> syntax should not be used when passing more than one closure argument
> (multiple_closures_with_trailing_closure).

I don't really understand what the warnings means and how to fix it. I already googled and looked into other posts on Stackoverflow but couldn't wrap my head around it.

My code looks like this:

```
Button(action: {
  address = "123 Fakestreet"
  onSubmit()
}) {
  Text("Start search")
}
```

**Question:** How can I refactor my code so the functionality stays the same but the warning goes away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to use labels for both arguments and not use this short version where the last closure omits the label:

```
Button(action: {
    address = "123 Fakestreet"
    onSubmit()
}, label: {
    Text("Start search")
})
```

When things get more complicated I actually suggest you to refactor everything into methods. Then you can use it this way:

```
private func onAddressButtonPressed() {
    address = "123 Fakestreet"
    onSubmit()
}

Button(action: onAddressButtonPressed) {
    Text("Start search")
}
```

Note that there are no brackets after the method `onAddressButtonPressed` (not `onAddressButtonPressed()`).

You can do the same with label part when appropriate

```
private func onAddressButtonPressed() {
    address = "123 Fakestreet"
    onSubmit()
}

private func addressButtonContent() -> some View {
    Text("Start search")
}

Button(action: onAddressButtonPressed, label: addressButtonContent)
```

Comment: Great answer! Fixes the warning and I now understand better what the cause of it was.